# How to append a string in excel formula for a list (DropDown)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a drop-down in `sheet2` at cell `F6` which contains a list from `sheet1` with formula `=Sheet1!$1:$1` and it gives me a drop with list of values like `Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,..`.
What I want to achieve is these values should be like `[Header1],[Header2],[Header3],..` 
Is there some way to achieve using excel formulas or VBA (apart from array with for loop). 
I'm searching for something like `"["&=Sheet1!$1:$1 &"]"`.

Comment: You can make another column / row which has the data in the format you need then you can refer to that range and make a dropdown list from that.

Comment: @newguy You mean manually ?

Comment: You can use a simple excel formula of string concatenation.

Comment: @newguy can u help me with the formula suppose i have n no of columns in a row.

Comment: If you only want it to look like that then number format `"["@"]"` may be an option :P

Comment: @newguy can you share me a example how can be loop through all cells of  Row 1 in excel.. I tried EntireRow, Rows etc. nothing seems working :(

Comment: @DirkReichel if you can explain a bit :D

Comment: just right-click the cell and format cells (or hit ctrl+1) -> number -> custom -> enter `"["@"]"` and the cell will look like `[Header1],[Header2]...` but the value still is `Header1,Header2...`

Comment: @DirkReichel lolzz, good one but won't gonna help me coz I want these values in dropdown later that means I need a in-memory replica with those `[Header1]...` for dropdown without disturbing the actual one.

Comment: with the build-in drop down you either need a copy or enter it manually... data-validation only accepts ranges or a direct list... (I was hoping that cheating is an option)

Answer (score 0):

Done it with below code (in case if anyone need a reference for How to read a Row in excel VBA)

```
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet
    Set objSheet = Sheets(1)
    Dim intLastCellIndexInRow As Integer
    intLastCellIndexInRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strRowValue As String

    For i = 1 To intLastCellIndexInRow
      If objSheet.Cells(1, i) <> "" Then
        strRowValue = strRowValue & ",[ " & objSheet.Cells(1, i) & "]"
      End If
    Next
```